# Grouping together char constants into a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to produce units in a textbox that change depending on the units of the value calculated. I'm not sure how to combine the character values together in the textbox, whether that's when i define them, or how I do that under the `Calculate_button_MouseClick` event

```
   `public const char N = (char)78;
    public const char per = (char)47;
    public const char m = (char)77;
    public const char squared = (char)50;
    public const char cubed = (char)51;
    public const char k = (char)75;
    public const char g = (char)71;
    public const char J = (char)74;
    public const char s = (char)83;`

    `private void Calculate_button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
             {
                switch (Radio)
                {
                    case 1:
                         textUnit.Text = (N + per + m + squared).ToString;
                }
                break;
             }
```

Comment: Just do `textUnit.Text = N.ToString() + per + m + squared;`

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to turn the first char in the set into a string. Once that happens, you can use + to keep appending more chars without having to explicitly turn each one into a string.

```
textUnit.Text = N.ToString() + per + m + squared;
```